# Set environment variables

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to set environment variables for an application so that **whenever** the process runs there wouldn't be no need to reset them.
In fact, I'm writing a .NET applications' profiler and I need to set environment variables for a list of processes (I get the list from a config file).
In other words, I previously know the processes to profile and I need to set the environment variables for them before they run

Comment: I really don't think there is. That would have to be implemented basically *everywhere* where there is a call to `CreateProcess` inside the OS.

Comment: Depends on the context of how it is being 'run' I would think.

Comment: Are these environment variables that can be set in the machine.config file, or will they be determined upon first run?

Answer (score 0):

> To work around this problem, use the interop services to set the environment variables. You can set an environment variable by using the Microsoft Platform Software Development Kit (SDK) SetEnvironmentVariable function.

[System.Environment class does not have a method to set the environment variable for the current process](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829145)

Comment: Actually, I know that we can't set environment variables for a running process and that we have to restart it. As I said in the question, I previously know the process to profile and I need to set environment variables before it runs.